# Spring-Security-UI

Tags: grails, spring-security

This is the first time i have attempted to use spring security UI in my Grails application.

I am currently using Spring Security Core and it works fine but I like the ideas of the UI plugin.

I have read through the documentation and I cannot see any single commant to run to set everything up with default values. Keeping in mind I have Spring Security Core already running.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "to set everything up with default values"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to override your auth view using

```
grails s2ui-override auth
```